# ¿Cómo evito valores aleatorios repetidos en PHP?

Tags: php, array, random

Debo realizar una matriz de 3 X 3 donde la letra X sea color Azul y la letra O color Rojo, deben aparecer al azar 3 letras O y 2 letras X. El problema es que no sé el cómo hacer para que $a y $b no tomen los mismos valores que las demás variables. Aquí algo de lo que he adelantado y el error que quiero evitar está en la imagen.

```
<?php


$a = rand(0,2);//primera x
$b = rand(0,2);
$c = rand(0,2);//segunda x
$d = rand(0,2);

$x = rand(0,2);//primer o
$y = rand(0,2);

$tablero[0] = array();
$tablero[1] = array();
$tablero[2] = array();

$o = "<img src='https://png.vector.me/files/images/3/3/337022/blue_circle_preview' width = '100px' height='100px' <br>";
$x = "<img src='https://icones.pro/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/icone-x-rouge.png' width = '100px' height='100px' <br>";
$cuadrovacio="<img src='https://www.arguments.es/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/cuadro-blanco.png' width = '100px' height='100px' <br>";

echo "<table border='1' style='border-color:green'>";

for ($i = 0; $i <= 2 ; $i++){
    
    echo "<tr>";
    
    for($j = 0; $j <= 2 ; $j++){
        
        $tablero[$i][$j]=$cuadrovacio;
           
            if($i==$x && $j==$y){ 

                $tablero[$i][$j]=$x;
                
        }   
        
        if($i==$c && $j==$d ){ //segunda X

               if ($c != $a && $d != $b){
                   
                   $tablero[$i][$j]=$x;
                   
               } 
                
        } 
        
        echo "<td>".$tablero[$i][$j]."</td>";
        
    }
    
    echo "</tr>";
    
}
?>
```

[image: ambas variables dieron el mismo valor]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ver... si lo que quieres es que `$a` y `$b` no tomen el mismo valor aleatorio, una forma de solucionarlo es asignar `$b` como lo haces, pero repitiendo intentos mientras sea igual a la recién asignada `$a`...

```
$a = rand(0,2);//primera x
while (($b = rand(0,2)) == $a);
```